# Getis-Ord Gi* (arcgis 'hotspot analysis') with python?

Tags: python, software-recommendations, spatial-statistics, hot-spot, pysal

Is it possible to compute Getis-Ord Gi* statistics (referred to as hotspot analysis in [arcgis](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/h-how-hot-spot-analysis-getis-ord-gi-spatial-stati.htm)) with a Python library?

Comment: I use QGIS frequently and have no idea what a hotspot analysis is. You might get better responses if you included at least a definition, or better yet a visual. Many of us know the ins- and outs- of geopandas and might be able to describe a workflow for "hotspot analysis" but not if we have to do research to understand the question.

Comment: Hi Jon, a hotspot analysis is defined as the following in ArcGIS' documentation: "Given a set of weighted features, identifies statistically significant hot spots and cold spots using the Getis-Ord Gi* statistic." More information can be found [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/h-how-hot-spot-analysis-getis-ord-gi-spatial-stati.htm).

Comment: It looks like a simple z-score type statistic...that would be easy enough to implement  yourself. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out PySAL: The Python Spatial Analysis Library

https://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've seen it. And I see in the docs they have a Getis-Ord Statistic. However, I don't think that will generate the same kind of output as the Hotspot analysis in ArcGIS. I might be mistaken but I think the Getis-Ord in PySal generates a spatial autocorrelation statistic. Is that right?

Comment: @JuanFranciscoSaldarriaga, yes the global Getis-Ord generates a statistic.  You want the local G (or G*) - https://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pysal.explore.esda.G_Local.html#pysal.explore.esda.G_Local

Comment: Great. Thank you. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Here's the updated link, as of July 2022: https://pysal.org/esda/generated/esda.G_Local.html#esda.G_Local